# Implementing dynamic plugins in Java

Tags: java, plugins, osgi, guice, peaberry

I'd like to implement a dynamic plugin feature in a Java application. Ideally:

- The application would define an interface `Plugin` with a method like `getCapabilities()`.
- A plugin would be a JAR `pluginX.jar` containing a class `PluginXImpl` implementing `Plugin` (and maybe some others).
- The user would put `pluginX.jar` in a special directory or set a configuration parameter pointing to it. The user should not necessarily have to include `pluginX.jar` in their classpath.
- The application would find `PluginXImpl` (maybe via the JAR manifest, maybe by reflection) and add it to a registry.
- The client could get an instance of `PluginXImpl`, e.g., by invoking a method like `getPluginWithCapabilities("X")`. The user should not necessarily have to know the name of the plugin.

I've got a sense I should be able to do this with [peaberry](http://code.google.com/p/peaberry/), but I can't make any sense of the documentation. I've invested some time in learning Guice, so my preferred answer would not be "use [Spring Dynamic Modules](http://www.springsource.org/osgi)."

Can anybody give me a simple idea of how to go about doing this using Guice/peaberry, OSGi, or just plain Java?

Comment: Peaberry and Spring DM are both layers over OSGi.  OSGi appears to do what you want (conceptually), but it will do it the 'OSGi-way' and won't map to your exact process, so a suggestion is to google for some OSGi tutorials.

Comment: OSGi looks about a hundred times more complicated than peaberry. Any links to good tutorials?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is actually quite easy using plain Java means:

Since you don't want the user to configure the classpath before starting the application, I would first create a URLClassLoader with an array of URLs to the files in your plugin directory. Use File.listFiles to find all plugin jars and then File.toURI().toURL() to get a URL to each file. You should pass the system classloader (ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()) as a parent to your URLClassLoader.

If the plugin jars contain a configuration file in META-INF/services as described in the API documentation for java.util.ServiceLoader, you can now use ServiceLoader.load(Plugin.class, myUrlClassLoader) to obatin a service loader for your Plugin interface and call iterator() on it to get instances of all configured Plugin implementations.

You still have to provide your own wrapper around this to filter plugin capabilites, but that shouldn't be too much trouble, I suppose.

Comment: Could you please explain this a little more detailed?

Comment: Not unless you have a more detailed question.

Comment: @jarnbjo: That totally works! Thanks! I'd still be interested to see a peaberry or OSGi solution tho...

Comment: At various places around SO I've seen people discouraging the use of ServiceLoaders. I think this answer explains it best and provides an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039467/java-serviceloader-with-multiple-classloaders/7237152#7237152

Comment: @Sergiy: No. Why should I?

Comment: @jarnbjo: Because following code in the text is way harder than having a piece of code. But, it's okay. I think I can write one myself once I will write it :-).

Comment: I've decided in favor of Java EE and JBoss AS to manage plugin dependencies and the like. This seems to be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

OSGI would be fine if you want to replace the plugins during runtime i.g. for bugfixes in a 24/7 environment. I played a while with OSGI but it took too much time, because it wasn't a requirement, and you need a plan b if you remove a bundle.

My humble solution then was, providing a properties files with the class names of plugin descriptor classes and let the server call them to register (including quering their capabilities).

This is obvious suboptimal but I can't wait to read the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you can leverage the [Service Provider Interface](http://www.developer.com/article.php/3848881)?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement plug-ins with Guice is with [Multibindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings). The linked page goes into detail on how to use multibindings to host plugins.

Comment: "Note that this mechanism cannot load or unload plugins while the system is running." It seems to me Multibindings require the plugin JARs to be on the classpath and the user to specify the Module classes in a configuration file. Maybe you can dynamically load the JARs in the plugins directory using a ClassLoader, but then you'd have to use something like a Service loader to find the Modules automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Apologize if you know this, but check out the `forName` method of [Class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). It is used at least in JDBC to dynamically load the DBMS-specific driver classes runtime by class name.

Then I guess it would not be difficult to enumerate all class/jar files in a directory, load each of them, and define an interface for a static method  `getCapabilities()` (or any name you choose) that returns their capabilities/description in whatever terms and format that makes sense for your system.

Comment: @Bandi-T: I've added some requirements above in response. I don't want to have to use something like `getPluginInstance("org.example.PluginXImpl")` or necessarily have the plugins directory in the classpath.

Comment: @Chris Conway: Then I'm sorry, that's beyond me, I'm not terribly advanced in Java.